# How Can I Get My Workflow RunID When Starting a New Workflow Instance?

Tags: web-services, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm using the webservices to interface with Informatica.  I have the following scenario:

```
1- I need to start a workflow.

2- Once the workflow is started, I need to poll the workflow to see what it's status is.

3- Once the workflow finishes, I need to retrieve the workflow log.
```

I've been using the `startWorkflow` web service call to start the workflow.  I've been using the `getWorkflowDetails` web service call to retrieve information about the workflow.  The problem I run into is that there can be many many workflows running, some of which have the same workflow name and instance name.  I need to monitor only the workflow that I am starting myself.  One of the parameters I can pass to `getWorkflowDetails` is the WorkflowRunId; using this seems to work.  However, the call to `startWorkflow` does not return the resulting runId of the workflow it started.  Are there any other ways to tie a `startWorkflow` command to a `getWorkflowDetails` in such a way so as to be certain I am processing the correct workflow run?  I see there are fields like "Key", available, but I'm not certain how to use them and the documentation (https://www.scribd.com/doc/38057161/Informatica-PowerCenter-9-0-Web-Services-Provider-Guide) seems kind of thin on details.

Comment: "some of which have the same workflow name and instance name" - Are you sure they have the same instance name as well? Are you passing instance name in startWorkflow?

Comment: Yes, the instance name is fixed and being passed in startWorkflow.

Comment: Looks like you can pass workflow run id as a parameter to `startWorkflow` as well. May be you can generate a number and pass them to both `startWorkflow` and `getWorkflowDetails`

Comment: How could I tell which numbers are not already in use elsewhere?

Comment: Valid point. Couldn't find any proper documentation for that either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startWorkflowEx` instead of `startWorkflow`

> ## startWorkflowEx
>
> Use this operation to start a workflow. The startWorkflowEx operation
>   returns the run instance ID of the workflow.Use the startWorkflowEx
>   operation instead of the startWorkflow operation to get the run ID of
>   the workflow startedby the operation.